# Notification system like facebook jewel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, jquery

Does anyone know any system wich work like facebook request, message, notification bubble system? somethig to alert on every user profile they have a new whatever  so they can reply . I mean obviously facebook has a great level but if anyone know about a similar system . I look for something similar en older question but, didn't find anything. Please let me know as well if theres is something on jquery or others. 
What matter to me is only a bubble counting how many new received has the actual user . I'm using Apache on Linux and aware of using something like commet (long polling) does anyone know a working sample of comet,Ajax Push,Reverse Ajax,Two-way-web, HTTP Streaming,HTTP server push (othewr name of comet)?

thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require something a little more than just Javascript.

Have a look into [Signal R](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)?

It uses long polling to provide fast and efficient responses.

Comment: Thank you for the help , if you remember something more, please let me now

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for because I think most people just implement this themselves, but you should look at [Humane JS](https://github.com/wavded/humane-js).

Comment: Thank you for the help , if you remember something more, please let me now